# It seems that enthalpy is maximized at equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

For a closed system at constant pressure $dH=TdS+VdP=TdS$.

On the other side we have that $dS \ge \delta Q/T$ that is $TdS \ge \delta Q$.

So we have $dH \ge \delta Q$ and if the transformation is adiabatic $dH \ge 0$.

From this inequality it seems that the enthalpy always increases in a spontaneous adiabatic process at constant pressure. However I know that at equilibrium enthalpy in minimized, something is is wrong with this argument, can you explain me better? Examples are welcome

Comment: For a closed system with no chemical reaction, how would you carry out an adiabatic process at constant pressure?

Comment: I would say that i can perform such a transformation putting a propeller inside an adiabatic box containing gas or liquid. However, i suspect that the fact that $dH=TdS+VdP$ derive from the assumption that $\delta W=-P{out}dV$...

Comment: That would not be at constant pressure because the temperature would rise.

Comment: obviously one wall is movable and outside pressure is fixed...

Comment: In that case, you would have to know how much work is done by the propeller.

Comment: I read that enthalpy should be minimized in a process at constant pressure

Comment: Reference please

Answer (score 1):

Heres an analysis of the case with a paddle doing work (for discussion).  Let $W_p$ represent the work done by the paddle.  Then, applying the first law to this adiabatic system at constant external pressure, we have $$\Delta U=W_p-P\Delta V$$or equivalently, $$\Delta H=W_p$$For an ideal gas, this reduces to $$nC_p(T_f-T_i)=W_p$$where n is the number of moles of gas.  So the final temperature is $$T_f=T_i+\frac{W_p}{nC_p}$$For an ideal gas, this gives an entropy change of $$\Delta S=nC_p\ln{\left(\frac{T_i+\frac{W_p}{nC_p}}{T_i}\right)}=nC_p\ln{\left(1+\frac{W_p}{nC_pT_i}\right)}$$This is the amount of entropy generated by the stirring paddle.

So does this mean that both enthalpy and entropy are maximized in the process at final equilibrium?

Comment: I appreciate this answer but i don't understand what is the point of ending question.I would say  that in this condition the enthalpy can only increase in any spontaneous transformation

Comment: If it is adiabatic at constant pressure with stirring, then yes.  So what?

Answer (score -1):

As @Chet Miller says in the comments, an adiabatic process at constant $P$  is impossible. But let us see why.

The conditions $T dS \geq \delta q$ and $\delta q = 0$ are equivalent to $dS= 0$. So, this is a closed system and the process is adiabatic and isentropic. But since
$$dH = T dS + V dP + \mu dN$$
and $dS=0 = dP=0=dN=0$, then $dH=0$, i.e.,  *nothing has changed!*

Your result is almost correct because it reduces to the exact equality $dH=0$. It is never satisfied as an inequality.